# List comprehension: Multiply each string to a single list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings and want to get a new list consisting on each element a number of times.

```
lst = ['abc', '123']
n = 3
```

I can do that with a for loop:

```
res = []
for i in lst:
    res = res + [i]*n
print( res )

['abc', 'abc', 'abc', '123', '123', '123']
```

**How do I do it with list comprehension?**

My best try so far:

```
[ [i]*n for i in ['abc', '123']  ]
[['abc', 'abc', 'abc'], ['123', '123', '123']]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> lst = ['abc', '123']
>>> n = 3
>>> [i for i in lst for j in range(n)]
['abc', 'abc', 'abc', '123', '123', '123']
```

The idea behind this is, you loop through the list twice and you print each of the element thrice.

See [What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34835951/4099593)

Comment: Side comment: I understand that wouldn't be a nested list? e.g. `[[1,2],[3,4]]`...

Comment: @Luis Yes, To get a nested list you need to add another pair of brackets. Something like this `[[i for j in range(n)] for i in lst]`. Take an hour off and go through those links. They are one of the best docs and will help you understand list-comps better. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done as:

```
>>> lst = ['abc', '123']
>>> n=3
>>> [j for i in lst for j in (i,)*n]
['abc', 'abc', 'abc', '123', '123', '123']
```